# next.config.js make a request inside

Tags: next.js

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a request and then use it in the config.
What I want to do is get the redirects and then push into configuration, but I have tried both synchronous and asynchronous ways of implementing it, but in both cases I am facing an error.

I need to keep it statically without any custom server, but serverless functions work.

Thanks.

I've tried both synchronous and asynchronous processing methods but couldn't resolve/achieve the result.